# Get indexes of a delegated selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Theres only 1 homeaddress on the page, so the index naturally returns 0 each time.
I have to use delegation of homeaddress because of htmldom changes that occur after.
How do i get the index of the input that triggered the keyup change event in the homeaddress?

```
var $homeInputs = $('#homeaddress').bind("keyup change", "input", function (e) {

         alert(e.delegateTarget.index(this));


        )};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input would be just `this` inside the event handler, and you should be using `on()`

```
var $homeInputs = $('#homeaddress').on("keyup change", "input", function (e) {
     console.log( $(this).index() ); // index based on siblings
     console.log( $homeInputs.find('input').index(this) ); // index based on inputs
                                                           // in $homeInputs parent
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

using index on the collection of `input` elements within `homeaddress` element. like below

```
var $homeInputs = $('#homeaddress').on("keyup change", "input", function (e) {    
     alert(  $('#homeaddress input').index(this) ); 
)};
```

From the **[Document](https://api.jquery.com/index/)**

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.